# Always insert the diacritic after a dead key

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

A followup question [on this subject](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/why-is-the-us-international-keyboard-layout-on-debian-different), perhaps any of you can help with that too. In Windows the layout for US International does/did this for me;

Typing <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> yields `I'd` (with no extra jams on the spacebar).

<kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> keys yield `é` (with no extra keys required).

For my LM Debian Edition desktop, I can never have both at once. Whatever layout I pick from the list, it's either the dead ' or the accent option.

What files do I have to edit for this to be active for US International?

My physical keyboard is a standard old-school IBM model layout with the euro next to the 5.

Comment: Nobody using Linux has been aware of this? Can't imagine..